# Lync enabled Windows Store app - File Transfers & Video Conversation - Lync SDK

Tags: lync-2010

We’re building a mobile solution on windows 8  i.e. Windows Store App, enabling real time collaboration features for maintenance personnel to connect with Customer Support team. We are leveraging Lync 2010 client SDK to support the collaboration needs.  The following are the key functionality we plan to enable with in the app

1. Text Conversations
2. Audio Conversations
3. Video Conversations
4. File Sharing (Send/Receive)
5. Remote Desktop Sharing
6. White board sharing

The following is the approach we’ve taken to integrate Lync with Windows Store app:

```
     Lync  will be running in UI Suppression Mode &  app will communicate with Lync client through SDK APIs, since the functionality is needed within the application.
     Lync Assemblies are wrapped in WCF service, since Lync SDK is not available for Windows Store apps.
```

We are currently able to enable Text & Audio Conversations through SDK in UI Suppression mode

```
     We right now are in need of an approach to enable File sharing between the app & Lync standard Client.
```

The option available for file transfers is through contextual conversations which requires GUID exchange as per the below references.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Lync-2010-Transferring-f766e7aa

We want to know if this scenario works between Windows Store App & standard Lync Client, if not request to advise the right approach.

```
     Along with File transfers, we'd also need the approach to enable video conversations, remote desktop/white board sharing with the current approach (Lync -> WCF Service -> Windows Store app) as from SDK it is not clear how we get stream data which can be forwarded to Windows Store app.
     Just found out that Desktop/Whiteboard/Resource sharing is not possible in UI Suppression mode, (reference below)
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/communicatorsdk/thread/1a7355fe-5c64-4b11-ba25-ce18d6bdd3dd

```
     The following behavior will be the concern from user experience point of view in case of Automation APIs, especially for Windows Store App, considering their full screen behavior
```

On starting a conversation, corresponding conversation window flashes and takes the user to desktop, user will have to manually go to the windows store app, post this event. The conversation window can be docked in case of desktop apps, i.e. WinForms/WPF using DockWindow(),is there a way for Windows Store app?
   Incoming call notifications are bubbled which disturbs the user experience with the Windows Store App
   User has to accept the file transfers to receive, in the conversation window, manually
Please advise if there is a best solution to avoid the above behavior if Automation API is the only option to go with for Windows Store App.

Comment: Did you find a way to fully integrate a video conversation feature into your Windows Store app?

Comment: Now with Lync 2013, would this work on Windows Store apps without using Suppression Mode?